# How to access Genymotion files from desktop?

Tags: file-system, genymotion

I want to access Genymotion file from my desktop. Is it possible?

What I find every where is about accessing desktop file from Genymotion!

Answer (score 0):

check this out

*C:\Users{username}\AppData\Local\Genymobile\Genymotion\ova*

Comment: Its type is "Open Virtualization Format Archive", while I need physical access to file.